# Can't display data in my php sessions

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I'm having a problem with my sessions forms. It's probably a simple answer but I can't seem to  figure it out.

My html:

```
<body>
<h1>Hobby Selection Page<br /></h1>
<form method="post" action="page1.php" id="hobbies" >
<p>
   <label for="Name">Name: </label>
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
</p>
<p>What is your favorite thing to do?<br/>
<select name="hobby">
   <option value="movies">Movies</option>
   <option value="read">Reading</option>
   <option value="music">Music</option>
   <option value="other">My hobby is not listed here</option>
 </select>
 <br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Clear Form"
/>
  </p>
  </form>
</body>
```

First php page (page1.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Click the link below';

$_SESSION['name'] = " . name . ";
$_SESSION['hobby'] = " . hobby . ";

// Second page
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php">page 2</a>';
?>
```

Second php page (page2.php):

```
<?php
// page2.php
session_start();
echo 'Your favorite activity:<br />';

echo $_SESSION['name'];
echo $_SESSION['hobby'];

echo '<br /><a href="page1.php">page 1</a>';
?>
```

My aim is to input data from the first html page and then send it to the first php page (to recieve the session variables) and then to be directed to the second php page where it should retrieve the session variables and display the input data I have entered/selected. I am able to get the html and php pages to display and be linked from one page to the next but I am unable to display (in first php page) the data I have inputted from the html page.

Comment: what is this `" . name . ";`?

Comment: it should be like this `$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name']` and same for the other one

Comment: and if you want to save data just in session and then display it, why you are using page1.php? put that code directly in page2.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In page1.php

Replace

```
$_SESSION['name'] = " . name . ";
$_SESSION['hobby'] = " . hobby . ";
```

By

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['hobby'] = $_POST['hobby'];
```

Answer (score 3):

your first page1.php should be like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Click the link below';

$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['hobby'] = $_POST['hobby'];;

// Second page
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php">page 2</a>';
?>
```

You are not getting data because you are storing string in `$_SESSION` not the text you entered in fields.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a few things. First give your submit button a name, like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" name="my_submit" />
```

Then, on `page1.php`, change this:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = " . name . ";
$_SESSION['hobby'] = " . hobby . ";
```

To something like this:

```
// Check if form was submitted. If so, get inputs.
if (isset($_POST['my_submit'])) {
   $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
   $_SESSION['hobby'] = $_POST['hobby']; 
}
```

That should get you started in the right direction. Later, you can add some validation to ensure that `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['hobby']` are filled in correctly before assigning them to the `$_SESSION`

Comment: Don't name your submit button `submit`, in case you ever add Javascript to the page and want to do `form.submit()`.